# Is there a way to customise the knitr::kable() output for Jira style tables?

Tags: r, jira, kable

I am trying to create a table output formatting that matches the style of Jira tables. Jira uses pipes like in the `knitr::kable(format = "pipe")` output but differs with regards to the column headers. Here is an example of my current table format using the `knitr` package:

```R
data("BOD")
BOD %>% tibble::tibble() %>% 
  head(n = 10) %>% 
  knitr::kable(format = "pipe")

> | Time| demand|
  |----:|------:|
  |    1|    8.3|
  |    2|   10.3|
  |    3|   19.0|
  |    4|   16.0|
  |    5|   15.6|
  |    7|   19.8|
```

Instead of using a line to separate the headers from the column content, Jira has a slightly different syntax:

```
|| Time|| demand||
|     1|     8.3|
|     2|    10.3|
|     3|    19.0|
|     4|    16.0|
|     5|    15.6|
|     7|    19.8|
```

Currently, I am removing the ›separation row‹ and modifying the first row:

```r
BOD %>% tibble::tibble() %>% 
  head(n = 10) %>% 
  knitr::kable(format = "pipe") -> tmp
tmp <- tmp[-2] 
tmp[1] <- stringr::str_replace_all(tmp[1], pattern = "\\|", replacement = "||")
tmp %>% writeClipboard() # Paste into Jira
# Output:
|| Time|| demand||
|    1|    8.3|
|    2|   10.3|
|    3|   19.0|
|    4|   16.0|
|    5|   15.6|
|    7|   19.8|
```

Is there a way to customise the `kable()` output in order to achieve Jira compatibility?

Answer (score 2):

There may be a better way, but for now you could write a function to return a Jira-style markdown table. For example:

```
library(tidyverse)

jirafy = function(x) {
  x = knitr::kable(x) 
  x = x[-2]
  x[1] = gsub("\\|", "||", x[1])
  
  return(x)
}

data("BOD")
y = BOD %>% 
  tibble() %>% 
  head(n = 10) %>% 
  jirafy

writeClipboard(y)
```

> ```
>   || Time|| demand||
>   |    1|    8.3|
>   |    2|   10.3|
>   |    3|   19.0|
>   |    4|   16.0|
>   |    5|   15.6|
>   |    7|   19.8|
> ```

I haven't used Jira, but, in case you haven't already seen it, the [`JirAgileR` package](https://matbmeijer.github.io/JirAgileR/index.html) is intended to allow you to use Jira from within R. Maybe `JirAgileR` will allow you to avoid copying/pasting and instead do everything programmatically.

You could also file a [feature request](https://github.com/matbmeijer/JirAgileR/issues) with the maintainer of `JirAgileR` to see if they can include a function to directly produce Jira-style markdown tables.

Comment: Your code does not work for me:
`Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : 
  cannot change class ‘"knitr_kable"’ into data.frame [translated]
Called from: as.data.frame.default(x)
`

Comment: `JirAgileR` allows you to retrieve but not send data. Anyways, this is beyond the scope of this question.